# How did Avraham save Terach?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, brit-milah, gehinnom, maseches-eruvin

The gemarah ([eiruvin 19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=19&format=text)) states that Avraham Avinu sits at the entrance to gehinom and doesn't allowed anyone circumcised to enter there. The Ariz'l (Sefer Likkutim, Parsha Vayera) states that the first one that Avraham saved from there was his father Terach. How can this be the case if Terach was never circumcised?

Comment: How do you know Terach was uncircumcised?

Comment: @DoubleAA there are many ma'amarei chazal which state that Avraham was the first person to circumcise himself. It is possible that Terach was born mahul like Noach but I know of no indication of such

Answer (score 10):

[Medrash Shochar Tov 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14050&st=&pgnum=213&hilite=) says that Terach was born circumcised.

Comment: you rock the party! excellent find.

Answer (score 3):

@Gershon's answer is spot on. But just in case not everyone agrees, I will offer another. You state in your comment that  there are many ma'amarei chazal which state that Avraham was the first person to circumcise himself. This leads you to the presumption that Terach did not have a bris at all.

However see Rashi on 15:15 from Bereshis Rabbah 30:4 that Terach did Teshuva toward the end of his life. In that case it is very probable that he also had a bris done afterwards. His death was long after Avrahams own Milah. (205[Terach died] - 70[Terach at Avraham birth] = 135).

It has just occurred to me that I am not sure why Terach was in Hell seeing as he had done Teshuva but I suspect that is a contradiction not based on my answer. Perhaps I'l ask it separately.

Comment: i like the stream of consciousness answering :)

Comment: @PM and i like upvotes ;-)

Comment: sorry, i don't have a real account or you'd get mine